# persist port routing from 80 to 8080

Tags: 12.04, networking, 13.10, iptables, routing

I use amazon EC2 instance which works via ubuntu. By default according security restrictions I can't bin my application to port 80, so I just bind it port 8080 and then set routing redirect from port 80 to 8080 via the following command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 8080
```

But I found that when I reboot the server this settings no longer active untill I invoke this command again.

So my question is how to enable port's redirect work even if system was rebooted?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add this command in `/etc/rc.local` , so it will be executed automatically after reboot .

Comment: Already did that, but still thanks for the answer

Comment: welcome my friend , thats a good trick

Comment: This works, but the real answer is @MeOMy's answer below.

Answer (score 16):

Use the `iptables-save` command instead.

Firewall rules should never go into `rc.local` script. `rc.local` is the last thing to be executed. If a block rule has been placed into `rc.local` there is a small time frame where an attacker can exploit a rule not being in place.

While it probably doesn't matter with this situation, it is still best to not get into a bad habit that may bite you later.

Comment: ran "sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 8080" and "sudo iptables-save". But routing was reset on reboot. Did I misunderstand how to do this?

Comment: The answer is incomplete.  `iptables-save > some-file-path` saves the rules, and then you would restore them via `iptables-restore < some-file-path` in `rc.local`.  Or install `iptables-persistent` which does this during boot as a service.

Comment: I'd like to understand how to do this. Be more specific, please

Answer (score 6):

Here is how the official iptables' documentation teaches us. [See here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#If_you_manually_edit_iptables_on_a_regular_basis)

Add these two lines in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
post-down iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
```

The line `post-down iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules` will save the rules to be used on the next boot.

Comment: Kudos for using the officially recommended method and, in this case, simplest method, to complete this task. I'd +2 if I could for using the KISS method.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a set of directories on Ubuntu 16.04 in `/etc/network` that will run scripts at various times during network initialization and shutdown:

```
if-down.d
if-post-down.d  
if-pre-up.d  
if-up.d
interfaces.d
```

So I found that I could dump the configuration as usual:

```
$ sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"
```

Then I created a file `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/restore:

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

... and flagged it executable

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/restore
```